# PhoneGap 3.0 iOS plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm starting to write a PhoneGap plugin for iOS, but I'm having trouble calling even a simple `NSLog()` in my Objective C code through `cordova.exec()`. With the recent release of PhoneGap 3.0 and the possibly confusing PhoneGap/Cordova naming, it's difficult to find resources online that provide any examples that are up-to-date or working.

Here is my barebones Objective C code:

```
// BLLog.h
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface BLLog : CDVPlugin

    - (void)log:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;

@end
```

and

```
#import "BLLog.h"

@implementation BLLog

- (void)log:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Hey, it works!");
}

@end
```

My html/javascript is pretty much the same as the code generated from a `phonegap create` with a few additions.

```
<html>
    <head>
     ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                app.log();
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code contains the `cordova.exec()`:

```
var app = {
    ...
    log: function () {
        alert('log');
        cordova.exec(function (){ console.log('success') }, function () { console.log('error') },  'BLLog', 'log', []);
    }
};
```

Here is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.metaio.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>GapApp</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />

    <feature name="BLLog" onload="true">
        <param name="ios-package" value="BLLog" />
    </feature>

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
</widget>
```

I also tried replacing the `<feature>` tags with `<plugin name="BLLog" value ="BLLog" \>`, but that didn't work either.

Finally, here is the XCode output:

```
2013-07-30 11:36:40.810 GapApp[407:907] ERROR: Plugin 'BLLog' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-07-30 11:36:40.812 GapApp[407:907] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "BLLog870927167",
  "BLLog",
  "log",
  [

  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing a search in github. Look at other plugins.

One thing that is confusing is they use the same names that xcode does. They maybe referencing the config.xml in the xcode project.

All of the plugins I saw on github were plugin.xml

https://github.com/sectore/phonegap3-native-ios-plugin?files=1

Take a look at this example. It may help.

Comment: Looks good. I will add comments about what I did after I fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your entire config.xml ?

I don't see declarations for PG Version or other required parameters.

I also thought it was suppose to be plugin.xml

```
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger"/>
    </feature>
    </config-file>

    <js-module src="www/console-via-logger.js" name="console">
        <clobbers target="console" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/logger.js" name="logger">
        <clobbers target="cordova.logger" />
    </js-module>

<header-file src="src/ios/CDVLogger.h" />
<source-file src="src/ios/CDVLogger.m" />

</platform>
```

I am definitely not qualified to answer this. Just an observation.

Comment: From the documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins. The first few paragraphs mention `config.xml`. I wish the docs gave examples of xml code in the context of the entire `config.xml`.